# Pagination and Filtering issues on jquery datatables

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

[image: This is my table view]

i use JQuery Datatables and i thought it was simple because JQuery Datatables has contain pagination and filtering box. My issues are the pagination is not working (you can see the table just Showing 1 to 1 of 1 entries althought the table has 2 entries) and also the filtering

here is my view code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Dashboard">
    <meta name="keyword" content="Dashboard, Bootstrap, Admin, Template, Theme, Responsive, Fluid, Retina">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/welcome/images/logo.png"> 
    <title>Home Guru</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/home/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--external css-->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/home/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/home/lineicons/style.css">    

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/home/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/home/css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/komponen/jquery-datatable/skin/bootstrap/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

  <section id="container" >
      <header class="header black-bg">
              <div class="sidebar-toggle-box">
                  <div class="fa fa-bars tooltips" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Toggle Navigation"></div>
              </div>
            <!--logo start-->
            <a href="#" class="logo"><b>E-School</b></a>
            <!--logo end-->
            <div class="top-menu">
                <ul class="nav pull-right top-menu">
                    <li><a class="logout" href="<?php echo site_url('c_user/logout');?>">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
      <!--header end-->

      <!--sidebar start-->
      <aside>
          <?php $this->load->view("menu.php"); ?>
      </aside>
      <!--sidebar end-->

      <!-- **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
      MAIN CONTENT
      *********************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->
      <!--main content start-->
     <section id="main-content">
          <section class="wrapper">
                <h3><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Daftar Siswa Anda</h3>
              <div class="row mt">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <div class="form-panel">
                      <table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover " id= "tabel-reward">
                              <h4><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Siswa</h4>
                              <hr>
                              <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <th>NISN</th>
                                  <th>Nama</th>
                                  <th>Kelas</th>
                                  <th></th>
                                  <th>Action</th>
                              </tr>
                              </thead>

                               <?php foreach($siswa as $student){?>
                              <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                  <td><?php echo $student->no_id;?></td>
                                  <td><?php echo $student->nama;?></td>
                                  <td><?php echo $student->nama_kelas;?></td>
                                  <td></td>
                                  <td>

                                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="<?php //echo base_url()."c_kuis/buatSoalKuis/".$kuis->id_ks."/".$kuis->jenis_kuis;?>" ><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Beri Reward</a> 
                                  </td>
                              </tr>
                              <?php } ?>
                              </tbody>

                          </table>  
                  </div>
                </div><!-- col-lg-12-->         
            </div><!-- row -->
          </section>
      </section>
      <!--main content end-->
      <!--footer start-->
      <!--<footer class="site-footer">
          <div class="text-center">
              <small class="copyright">&copy; 2017 E-School SMP Negeri 1 Cikarang Barat</small>
          </div>
      </footer>-->
      <!--footer end-->
  </section>

    <!-- js placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/home/js/jquery.js"></script>
   <!-- <script src="<?php //echo base_url(); ?>assets/home/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/home/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/home/js/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.js"></script>-->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/home/js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/home/js/jquery.nicescroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/home/js/jquery.sparkline.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/komponen/jquery-datatable/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/komponen/jquery-datatable/skin/bootstrap/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $('#tabel-reward').DataTable();  
        } );
    </script>

    <!--common script for all pages-->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/home/js/common-scripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help me to find the issues on my code. thank you.

Comment: bydefault there is 10 record per page shown by data-table. since you have only 2 records after filter that's why only 1 page will show.So what you want?Check this:- http://prntscr.com/fvi3nf

Comment: @AlivetoDie I've try to add some data too.. until it has 12 entries... but it also not working. Is there anything wrong in my code?

Comment: And also in the end of the table you see the word "Showing 1 to 1 of 1 Entries" if the table has 2 records. Isn't that word will like this "Showing 1 to 1 of 2 Entries"? @AlivetoDie

Comment: you said after filter. when you filter and if data is 12 then data-table will show you 2 page in your pagination. so it's not about you add 12 row, it's about after filter how many records come? also check your browser console that any error is there or not?

Comment: No, filtering is still not working yet. that picture... i captured before i insert more records. @AlivetoDie

Comment: There is 1 error when i debug it @AlivetoDie but i still don't know what to do

Comment: There's no error anymore now.. i've fixed it.. but i still don't know why the filtering is still not working.. and the pagination keep says it's "1 entries" @AlivetoDie

Comment: you need to create a fiddle example of your problem so that we can check and rectify.

Comment: Nice idea! i will try! thanks @AlivetoDie